# Where can I find the doc for the function GetObject in Microsoft Javascript?

Tags: com, jscript, wsh, windows-scripting

I cannot find the doc for the function `GetObject` available in Microsoft Javascript.

I tried with no luck https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?terms=javascript%20getobject where I found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/getobject-function which could be good enough for me even if it is related to Visual Basic for Applications... but I would like to find the doc for Javascript.

Comment: Maybe because it’s called [JScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/hbxc2t98(v=vs.84))?

Comment: @user692942 thank you... if you add an answer I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft's implementation of JavaScript (ECMAScript Version 3) is known as JScript. Like VBScript it’s been hidden away in the Microsoft Documentation archives.

- [JScript (ECMAScript3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/hbxc2t98(v=vs.84))

The function can be found in the language reference under Functions. Here is a direct link to [`GetObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/7tf9xwsc(v=vs.84)).